# How to escape an asterisk?

Tags: powershell

When I try to do anything with the path `HKCR:\*` it just takes forever. So I assume it takes the asterisk as wildcard.

```
Test-Path -Path HKCR:\*
```

What I've tried

```
HKCR:\\*
HKCR:\`*
'HKCR:\*'
```

Comment: `Test-Path -Path 'HKCR:\*'` Using the single quote should take it as a literal path rather than using the wildcard.

Comment: Hmmm ... seem like  `Test-Path` does not _like_ the short path name. This way seems to work: `Test-Path -Path 'REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\`*'`  ... and  the backtick seems to work for the literal path with the [asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk) `HKCR:\*`

Comment: @Drew: Single quotes make no difference here. What matters is what parameter the argument binds to, which is `-Path`, which by design interprets arguments as wildcard expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `LiteralPath` parameter rather than the `Path` parameter to prevent characters from being interpreted as wildcards.

```
Test-Path -LiteralPath HKCR:\*
```

Comment: In my environment this returns $false although the path exists. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Olaf It returns false in my environment as well. `Get-PSDrive` shows why; `REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is not mapped to a PowerShell drive.

Comment: got it ... makes perfectly sense this way ...  thanks.